# compare 2 ranges using arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to check if each particular value (text&numbers) from a range 1 exists in range 2. If not, this value has to be added to the range 2.

For Each loop takes too much time. I want to try with arrays:

1. create an array with all values from range 1
2. create an array with all values from range 2
3. check if the element of array 1 is not empty
   3.1 if not, check if the element exists in array 2
   3.1.1 if yes, go to next element of array 1
   3.1.2 if no:
   3.1.2.1 add the element to array 2
   3.1.2.1 add the element to the range 2 (in workbook)
   3.2 if yes, go to next element of array 1
4. go to next element of array 1 and repeat third step

   ```
    Public Sub Table_And_Layout()
    Dim wsRoadmap As Worksheet
    Dim wsBacklog As Worksheet
    Dim bList As Range
    Dim Arr() As Variant

    Dim rListLastCol As Long
    Dim TempRng As Variant
    Dim element As Variant 'Range

    Set wsBacklog = Sheets("Backlog")
    Set wsRoadmap = Sheets("Roadmap")

    Set bList = wsBacklog.Range("C7", wsBacklog.Cells(bListLast, 3))
    bListLast = wsBacklog.Cells(wsBacklog.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Arr = wsRoadmap.Range("C6", wsRoadmap.Cells(rListLastRow, rListLastCol))

    For Each element In Arr
        If Not IsEmpty(element) Then
            Set TempRng = bList.Find(element.Value)
            If TempRng Is Nothing Then
                wsBacklog.Cells(bListLast + 1, 3).Value = wsRoadmap.Cells(element.Row, element.Column).Value
                bListLast = wsBacklog.Cells(wsBacklog.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        End If
    Next element
    End Sub
   ```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: "Set TempRng = bList.Find(element.Value)" --> gives an error: Object required

Comment: Why don't you use dictionnary ?

Comment: `Arr` is an array and array elements do not have a `Value` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OPTION 2 is the fastst one:

```
Public Sub Table_And_Layout()
    Dim wsRoadmap As Worksheet
    Dim wsBacklog As Worksheet
    
    Dim bList As Range
    Dim bListLast As Long
    Dim rList As Range
    Dim rListLastCol As Long
    
    Dim TempRng As Variant
    Dim element As Variant
    
'****************************
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer
'****************************

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer
    
    Set wsBacklog = Sheets("Backlog")
    Set wsRoadmap = Sheets("Roadmap")

    ' unlock sheet
    wsBacklog.Unprotect
        
    bListLast = wsBacklog.Cells(wsBacklog.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set bList = wsBacklog.Range("C7", wsBacklog.Cells(bListLast, 3))
        
    Set rList = wsRoadmap.Range("C6:BB100")
    
    ' find last not empty column
    rListLastCol = wsRoadmap.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column
        'MsgBox "Last Col: " & rListLastCol
        
    ' find last not empty row
    rListLastRow = wsRoadmap.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
        'MsgBox "Last Row: " & rListLastRow
        
    Set rList = wsRoadmap.Range("C6", wsRoadmap.Cells(rListLastRow, rListLastCol))
         'MsgBox rList.Address

'OPTION 1 (works but very slow)
'    ' filling backlog
'    For Each element In rList
'        If Not element Is Nothing Then
'            Set TempRng = bList.Find(element.Value)
'            If TempRng Is Nothing Then
'                wsBacklog.Cells(bListLast + 1, 3).Value = wsRoadmap.Cells(element.Row, element.Column).Value
'                bListLast = wsBacklog.Cells(wsBacklog.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
'            End If
'        End If
'    Next element

'OPTION 2 (works fast)
    ' declare array for roadmap
    Dim Arr() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array.
    Arr = wsRoadmap.Range("C6", wsRoadmap.Cells(rListLastRow, rListLastCol)) ' Arr is now an allocated array
        '        Dim NumRows As Long
        '        Dim NumCols As Long
        '        MsgBox NumRows = UBound(Arr, 1) - LBound(Arr, 1) + 1
        '        MsgBox NumCols = UBound(Arr, 2) - LBound(Arr, 2) + 1

    ' declare array for backlog
    Dim ArrB() As Variant
    ArrB = wsBacklog.Range("C6", wsBacklog.Cells(bListLast, 3))
    
    'filling backloga
    For Each element In Arr
        If Not IsEmpty(element) Then
            Set TempRng = bList.Find(element)
            If TempRng Is Nothing Then
                wsBacklog.Cells(bListLast + 1, 3).Value = element
                bListLast = wsBacklog.Cells(wsBacklog.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        End If
    Next element
    
'OPTION 3 (does not work)
'    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
'        For j = LBound(ArrB) To UBound(ArrB)
'            If Not IsEmpty(i) Then
'                If Arr(i) = ArrB(j) Then
'                    wsBacklog.Cells(bListLast + 1, 3).Value = Arr(i)
'                End If
'            End If
'        Next
'    Next
  

'*************************************************************************************
'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
'*************************************************************************************
        
End Sub
```

PS. Thank you SJR!